# get rid of hiccup on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I am using jquery ui toggle for a dropdown on a map legend.

The problem is that when you click on the class to show the drop down div; there is a slight hiccup where the div jumps a bit. Anyone know why this is happening? 
Here's my html:

```
<h3 id="conservation-header">
<i class="icon-stop" style="color:#739435;"></i> 
<i class="icon-caret-down" style="color:#fff;"></i> 
<span class="dropdown">Conservation</span> &nbsp; 
<span class="extras" style="color:#739435;">[
<a style="color:#739435;" id="conservationMoreLink" href="#">info</a>] &nbsp; [
<a style="color:#739435;" >images</a>]</span>
</h3>

       <div class="dropThis" style="display:none;">
       <ul>
         <li>Preservation</li>
         <li>Silviculture</li>
         <li>Limited Agriculture consistent with resource value</li>
         <li>Environmental Services</li>
         <li>Mitigation</li>
         <li>Recreation</li>
         <li>Roadway Connections</li>
         </ul>
       </div>
```

[Here's my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UA3Bg/)

thanks in advance

Comment: Give your `.dropThis` a `position:absolute;`.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166299/jquery-slidetoggle-jumps-around

Comment: The position:absolute addition seems to be simplest fix. Thank you @putvande

Answer (score 2):

Set the `ul` style to:

```
margin-top: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to fix hiccups/jumps in the past by setting the backface- visiblity of the element (or any parent element) to `'hidden';`

If you're testing this in Chrome, try adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to the body element and see if the problem is fixed.

More info on [backface- visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility).